# Не понимаю смысл поля "Длина/Значения" в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

На данный практикуюсь в создании сайтов. Для этого приходится создавать различные таблицы в БД. Всё работает хорошо, но мне непонятно, на что влияет поле **"Длина/Значения"**, которое у меня для *int* автоматические выставляется как *int(11)*. Я понимаю, что это не числовое ограничение, а связано с выводом данных. Но на деле я с этим как-то не сталкивался.

[image: БД]

Можно пример PHP кода, в котором я буду видеть разницу, например, между *int(3)* и *int(11)*?

Comment: Эта характеристика достаточно давно deprecated. И уже parsed but ignored.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что при выводе данных через PHP я никогда не увижу разницы между int(3) и int(11)? Кстати, там есть не только "Длина", но и какие-то "Значения"..

Comment: При выводе - однозначно да. Не увидите.

Comment: А в каком месте я вообще могу увидеть разницу между int(3) и int(11)? Хочется наглядно увидеть хоть где-то, хоть на что-то влияние этого поля.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html и https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html - иными словами, чтобы увидеть, надо найти/поставить весьма древнюю версию. Последнее, где можно было наблюдать разницу - это влияние length на вывод значений с атрибутом zerofill.

Comment: @Akina понял, спасибо